# How can I cumulatively sum defaultdict with same parameter? (Python)

Tags: python, defaultdict

I recently started using defaultdict in python.

When ım using defaultdict ı struggled to cumulative sum with same parameter.

In my case ı have defaultdict like that:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
        {'11106000022': [(216.0, datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 5, 0, 0)),
                         (216.0, datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 5, 0, 0)),
                         (370.0, datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 6, 0, 0)),
                         (110.0, datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 6, 0, 0))],
         '11106000053': [(89.0, datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 5, 0, 0)),
                         (500.0, datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 7, 0, 0))],
         '11106000083': [(50.0, datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 15, 0, 0))],
         '11106000126': [(170.0, datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 14, 0, 0))]}
```

For example, I want to cumulatively sum the numbers that fall on the same date in the first key. Finally I want to do this for all defaultdict.

```
{'11106000022': [(432.0, datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 5, 0, 0)),
                 (370.0, datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 6, 0, 0)),
                 (110.0, datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 6, 0, 0))]}
```

So in this output the value 216 is now 432 (**same datetime**).
Is there a way to solve this problem using map or dict comprehension . Or maybe something else.

Comment: In your second code block where does 512 come from? Are you expecting that to be 432? Or was that a typo and it supposed to be 521 for 216 + 216 + 89? fyi there's also a missing `]` near the end of your first code block

Comment: You right. I did some typo and miscalculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
data = defaultdict(...)
for key, val in data.items():
    sums_by_date = defaultdict(float)
    for item in val:
        sums_by_date[item[1]] += item[0]
    data[key] = [(v, k) for k, v in sums_by_date.items()]
```

which results in

```
{'11106000022': [(432.0, datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 5, 0, 0)), (480.0, datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 6, 0, 0))], 
'11106000053': [(89.0, datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 5, 0, 0)), (500.0, datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 7, 0, 0))], 
'11106000083': [(50.0, datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 15, 0, 0))], 
'11106000126': [(170.0, datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 14, 0, 0))]}
```

Could probably try to condense some of the above into fancy, more obscure comprehensions also.

Comment: Thanks it works on my case.I was using itertools.groupby try to do that. Such a waste time

Comment: If I have more than one value (i mean index 0) like  
{'11106000022': [(216.0, 25, datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 5, 0, 0)),
                           (216.0, 25, datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 5, 0, 0))]}
What can i do to sum ?

Comment: @TugrulGokce It depends on what the "sum" of these two data points actually mean - should the aggregate result be like `[(512.0, 50, dt(2022, 10, 5))]` or  `[(512.0, [25, 25], dt(2022, 10, 5))]` or do the 2 only merge if the dates are the same _and_ the second value is the same so then your example the result should still as separate data points? something else? Broadly speaking, just use another data structure like a tuple or a custom class instead of `float` for the values in the `_sums_by_date` dictionary?